# How can I list the Startup Type of a serive running on a remote machine?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find out the startup type of a service running on a remote machine.

I've tried the below but it gives me the Start Mode rather than the Startup Type.

```
[cmdletbinding()]            

 param(            
 [string[]]$Service,            
 [switch]$Disabled,            
 [switch]$Automatic,            
 [switch]$Manual,            
 [string]$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName            
 )            
 foreach($Ser in $Service) {            
 try {            
  $Obj = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$Ser'"-ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop            
  $Obj | select Name, DisplayName, StartMode            
 } catch {            
  Write-Error " Failed to get the information. More details: $_"            
 }            
}



.\Get-ServiceStartupType.ps1 –Service wscsvc –ComputerName Computername
```

The Service is "wscsvc" Security Center

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `Get-Service` instead of `Get-WmiObject`:

```
$svc = Get-Service wscsvc
$svc.StartType
```

Used in your code like this:

```
$Obj = Get-Service $Ser -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction Stop            
$Obj | select Name, DisplayName, StartType
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
Get-Service -name $ser -computername $computername | select-object Name,StartType
```

Instead of get-wmiobject.  I've also used the pipeline instead of a variable to make the code a little cleaner.